# Backload and jquery File Uploader - Do not display uploaded files properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, file-upload

I'm using MVC 4 and Backload file uploader with jquery client side scripting.  I used nuget to get the Demo package which downloads the controller and view as a starting point.

My problem is on my local server and my online server, after I upload files the application does not accurately display all the files uploaded.  Often it get's stuck displaying just 4 or 5 files and ignores the rest.  Even if I delete one of the files being displayed and refresh the page it still shows the same 4 or 5 images.  I have verified that the files are being uploaded and/or deleted by the application.  I tried clearing the cache by hitting cntl F5 but to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to correct this problem.  Below is the view and controller that comes from the demo downloaded from NuGet.

CONTROLLER:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Spotless_Interiors.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class BackloadDemoController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }


    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "File Upload";

}

@section topScripts {
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

    <!-- We use Backloads. bundeling feature to register only those client side javascript and style files of the jQuery File Upload Plugin
         that are needed  -->
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/fileupload/bootstrap/BasicPlusUI/css")

     <!-- Bootstrap CSS fixes for IE6 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/FileUpload/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-ie6.debug.css"><![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
}

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    <!-- We use Backloads. bundeling feature to register only those client side javascript and style files of the jQuery File Upload Plugin that are needed  -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fileupload/bootstrap/BasicPlusUI/js")

    <!-- Initialize the jQuery File Upload Plugin -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/FileUpload/backload.demo.js"></script>

}


 <div>
        <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
        <form id="fileupload" action="/Backload/UploadHandler" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
            <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/"></noscript>
            <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
            <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                <div class="span7">
                    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                        <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Add files...</span>
                        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                        <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Start upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Cancel upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                        <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                    <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
                    <span class="fileupload-loading"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- The global progress information -->
                <div class="span5 fileupload-progress fade">
                    <!-- The global progress bar -->
                    <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                        <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- The extended global progress information -->
                    <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
            <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
        </form>  

        <!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
        <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
        {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
            <tr class="template-upload fade">
                <td>
                    <span class="preview"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
                    {% if (file.error) { %}
                        <div><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
                    {% } %}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</p>
                    {% if (!o.files.error) { %}
                        <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
                    {% } %}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% if (!o.files.error && !i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                        <button class="btn btn-primary start">
                            <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                            <span>Start</span>
                        </button>
                    {% } %}
                    {% if (!i) { %}
                        <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                            <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                            <span>Cancel</span>
                        </button>
                    {% } %}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% } %}
        </script>
        <!-- The template to display files available for download -->
        <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
        {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
            <tr class="template-download fade">
                <td>
                    <span class="preview">
                        {% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
                        {% } %}
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="name">
                        <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
                    </p>
                    {% if (file.error) { %}
                        <div><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
                    {% } %}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"{% if (file.delete_with_credentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                        <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% } %}
        </script>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all files uploaded/deleted correctly and you cleared the client side cache, this seems to be a server side caching issue. You should use Fiddler to inspect the chache headers of the request and response.

Do you have set any caching options in the configuration file? Try to set something like this in the config file:
`<cacheManager lastModified="false" etag="false" expires="0" location="None" mustRevalidate="true" />`. Note, as far as I know, cacheManager is a Pro feature, it works locally but not on a remote server with the Standard license (my company has an Enterprise license with source code)

But as I said above, I think it is more related to your server side cache settings. So, upload one file after another, then delete a file and inspect all requests/responses with Fiddler. The Json resonse from Backload should always reflect the current file state even if a 304 is returned. Disable all server side cache settings in the Web.config.

Comment: It was a server side cache problem.  Instead of location = "none" as you suggested, I put in location = "NoCache" and it worked.  Thank you so much for the help.